# How to fix an "ImportError: No module named numpy" on AWS EC2 Server with AMI Linux but it installed?

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

For five days or so I could start a script with numpy without problems. I installed it like here in the forum proposed and it worked. when I try to start another python script with numpy today, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neuralTensorNetworkAcc.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

But numpy seems to be installed:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-106 sk-learn]$ sudo yum install numpy                    Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
Package python26-numpy-1.7.2-8.16.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

What is wrong? How to fix that bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: run `python --version` to ensure that python2.6 is set to be the default python version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325923/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-error-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417941/python-import-error-no-module-named-does-exist

Comment: My python version: Python 2.7.9

Comment: If the default python version is not 2.6, you can change it using an alias: `alias python=/usr/bin/python2.6`. To make that alias permanent, add it to your `~/.bashrc` file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256389/7560187) is a great post for further reading.