# How do I properly import/use classes and modules I built in Python in other classes/modules?

Tags: python

I am moving from a functional approach to a more object oriented approach for building a library of valuation models for (derivative) financial instruments in Python.
I keep getting error messages that I do not understand.

Let me first explain what I am doing:

1. I create a class where I define and store the common attributes of the product for which I am building a valuation model. As an example, let’s work with the class `Option`:

   ```
   class Option(object):
     def _init_ (self, S0, ..., params):
          self.So = S0
          ...
          self.div = params.get('div',0)
          ...
   ```
2. I then build a class for the valuation of the option (let’s work with a binomial model)

   ```
   from Option import Option

   class BinomialOption(Option):    
       def _setup_parameters_(self):
           self.X = ...
           ........
   ```

When I do this, get an import error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Option'
```

I do not understand why this happens. I created a class, and I ran it before running the BinomialOption class.

Why do I get this error message? And how do I prevent it?

Comment: possible answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files

Comment: Where is Option defined? Is it in a file called Option.py? Is that file on your Python path, or in the same directory as the one that defines BinomialOption?

Comment: Note that `'_init_' != '__init__'`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess, you have a directory for libs and other directory for the programs, haven't you? If that's the case, you have a problem with your path.

In StackOverflow you have already similar questions with the answer:

- [How to fix "ImportError: No module named ..." error in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325923/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-error-in-python)
- [Python import error: 'No module named' does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417941/python-import-error-no-module-named-does-exist)