# problem with paths after installing z3 without being root

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, z3

I have installed **Z3** on a **remote server** where **I am not Root**. I changed the **prefix** during the installation to my directory where I have write access, The installation went smoothly and now I have two directories in my home directory one for the project and one where I unzipped/build/installed z3. when I want to execute a python script that includes:

```
 from z3 import *
```

I receive this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'z3'
```

I think it's a problem related to paths and my python file can't get to the z3 module, I don't know how to fix this especially that python3 was installed by the root and not by me.

Comment: Have you added the directoy where you have installed z3 to your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: as a **non portable** hack, you can also prepend that line with `sys.path.append('path/to/z3')`

Comment: @basel117 Could you give some additional infos as asked in the comments here?

Comment: no I didn't add them to the pythonpath, I am doing that right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/338768/608639), [import error: 'No module named' *does* exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23417941/608639), etc.

Comment: I have added Z3 to PYTHONPATH variable environments as suggested in the last step in this link [ http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/manuals/current/manual/index-seo.php/SMT____Z3-INSTALLATION ] but I still can't get my python code to run. how do I check if it was added successfully?

Answer (score 0):

One work around for this is by importing packages using their paths, like

```
from ~/z3_folder import *
```

Please share if it works.