# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_popup_view_field'

Tags: python, django

You see that all is installed, but when I run `runserver` I got this error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_popup_view_field'
>
> [p-amc-dgps-er@192-168-150-254 Invest_App]$ sudo pip install
>   django-popup-view-field [sudo] Mot de passe de p-amc-dgps-er : 
>   DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
>   2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python
>   2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
>   Requirement already satisfied: django-popup-view-field in
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.5.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: Django>=1.8 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   django-popup-view-field) (1.11.26) Requirement already satisfied: pytz
>   in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   Django>=1.8->django-popup-view-field) (2018.9)

Comment: Install the dependencies `django-popup-field` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your project's `settings.py`:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'popup_field',
...
]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add this module to **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_popup_view_field',
    ...
]
```

Comment: i add it and always same problem

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me comment because I don't have enough rep, but are you installing django-popup-view-field within a virtual environment? And are you also running `runserver` within that same virtual environment? it seems to be the most common issue when receiving the error "ModuleNotFound". Please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417941/import-error-no-module-named-does-exist) it might help you.

If all else fails, sometimes it helps just to completely come out of that terminal and try again.