# How to include path of tensorflow on ubuntu, python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to execute an old (python 2.7, tensorflow 1.3) program .
`conda list tensorflow` shows tensorflow is installed. But the program cannot import tensorflow.

```
>python train.py
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 5, in 
import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow

I read [Python error "ImportError: No module named"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338768/python-error-importerror-no-module-named)  and [import error: 'No module named' *does* exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417941/import-error-no-module-named-does-exist)

I think the permisson of file is okay.

```
>ls -al ./anaconda/envs/py2_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opt_einsum/backends/tensorflow.py
    -rw-rw-r-- 2 myid myid 3797 Oct 11  2019 ./anaconda/envs/py2_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opt_einsum/backends/tensorflow.py
```

After reading other answers when same error was encountered , I think I need to include the path for tensorflow to $PATH or $PYTHONPATH.
I am not sure which folder needs to be included. How to find the folder that needs to be included?

```
>find . -name tensorflow.py
./anaconda/envs/py2_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opt_einsum/backends/tensorflow.py
./anaconda/pkgs/opt_einsum-2.3.2-py_0/site-packages/opt_einsum/backends/tensorflow.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like virtual environment is not activated before executing the train.py

```
#Activate the Environment
source activate py2_env

# Verify the tensorflow installation
py2_env$python
>import tensorflow as tf
>tf.__version__

#Execute your code
py2_env$ python train.py
```